# Closes after opening Google Ads

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob

I added a rewarded google admob ad to my game. It seamlessly display on devices under Android 6.0. But the ad opens on 7.0 and closes in 1 second.
I would be very glad if you help.

Comment: Try connecting your device and opening adb logcat while testing the ads. It should print out some helpful logs.

Answer (score 0):

We've solved it using Google's new rewarded api.
https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/rewarded-ads